# How to make this animation properly with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to make an animation, you can see my efforts at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/petarvasilev/krvxLr0c/3/). And here is the code I've used:

```js
/*  JavaScript:  */

    var app = function () {
        var self = this;
    
        var allBoxes = $('.box');
        var shadow = $('#shadow');
        var busy = false;
    
        self.init = function () {
            self.events();
        };
    
        self.getBoxLeftPosition = function(id)
        {
            var left = 100;
    
            if (id == 'box2')
            {
                left = 300;
            } else if (id == 'box3')
            {
                left = 500;
            } else if (id == 'box4')
            {
                left = 700;
            }
    
            return left;
        };
    
        self.events = function () {
    
            allBoxes.on('hover mousemove', function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                var currentBox = $(this);
    
                if (currentBox.hasClass('inactive') && !busy)
                {
                    busy = true;
                    currentBox.removeClass('inactive').addClass('active').animate({
                        left: '-=30',
                        width: 260
                    }, 400, function () {
                        busy = false;
                    });
    
                    shadow.fadeIn(400);
                }
            });
    
            $('body').mousemove(function(event) {
                var currentBox = $('.active');
                var leftValue = self.getBoxLeftPosition(currentBox.attr('id'));
    
                if (currentBox.length > 0)
                {
                    currentBox.stop();
                    currentBox.animate({
                        left: leftValue,
                        width: 200
                    }, 300, 'swing', function () {
                        currentBox.removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
                    }, 300);
    
                    shadow.fadeOut(300);
                }
            });
    
        };
    
        return self;
    };
    
    var main = new app();
    main.init();
```

```css
/*  CSS:  */

html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
    
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 420px;
}
    
.box div {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
    
#box1 {
  left: 100px;
  background: pink;
}
    
#box2 {
  left: 300px;
  background: skyblue;
}
    
#box3 {
  left: 500px;
  background: orange;
}
    
#box4 {
  left: 700px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
    
#shadow {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/Vz0GTzpQVaxmlIvvGgg64CSxcYBbHzu7gMQERduJ4qjU5HAg8KfisFFQvIqvKL5Vn7LIy6HZ=w1920-h916');
  z-index: 10;
}
    
.inactive {
  z-index: 5;
}
   
.active {
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML:  -->

<div id="box1" class="box inactive">
  <div id="copy1">Copy 1</div>
</div>
    
<div id="box2" class="box inactive">
  <div id="copy2">Copy 2</div>
</div>
    
<div id="box3" class="box inactive">
  <div id="copy3">Copy 3</div>
</div>
    
<div id="box4" class="box inactive">
  <div id="copy4">Copy 4</div>
</div>
    
<div id="shadow"></div>
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve in words: I have 4 boxes and whenever a user hovers over one of them that box needs to expand a little and everything else needs to be grayed out and whenever the mouse leaves the box it needs to go back to it's original state.

In my jsfiddle I got it working to a point but it's buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krvxLr0c/11/)

```
$('.box').hover(function(){
$(this).siblings().addClass('inactive');
}, function(){
$(this).siblings().removeClass('inactive');
});
```

tried to do it with pure css but sadly there's no such thing as `prev sibling selector` in `css`. Its kinda jumpy because of `z-index` getting immediately change on hover.

Comment: That is close to what I need but I really need the #shadow element to pop in because there is other stuff on the page that needs to be greyd out.

Comment: what do you mean to pop in? you mean like a modal?

Comment: yes, like a modal which greys out the whole page apart from the box you are currently hovering on

Comment: @PetarVasilev i updated my answer please check it out and accept if correct. thanks!

Comment: Wow looks great on jsfiddle. I'll implement it in my projec and if t it works fine I'll accept.

Comment: It worked ! The only problem now is that I don't want scale the children of the boxes : (

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same effect even with CSS

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.item', function(e){
    var me = $(this);
    $('.item').not(this).addClass('greyed');
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.item', function(e){
    $('.item').removeClass('greyed');
});
```

```css
ul,li{
list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;
}
ul{
    width:400px;
}
li, .item {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;   
}
li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.item {
    background-color: #eee;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.item:hover {
    width:110px;
    z-index:2;
}

.red{
  background: red;
}

.pink{
  background: pink;
}

.blue{
  background: blue;
}

.yellow{
  background: yellow;
}

.greyed{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="item red"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item blue"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item yellow"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item pink"></div>
    </li>
   
</ul>
```

Comment: why **only** the prefixed version ?

Comment: This is also buggy, it doesn't achieve what I want

Comment: Oh..I forgot the grey out part...i'll update the code

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did.

First, I found that the background image in your css is not a valid resource, so I replaced it with regular background color (it's transparent black, you may want to adjust it).

Second, I changed `allBoxes.on('hover mousemove'` to `allBoxes.on('mouseover'`, and `$('body').mousemove` to `allBoxes.on('mouseout'`.

Third, I removed the `$busy` flag tracking.

Fourth, I changed `var currentBox = $('.active');` to `var currentBox = $(event.target);`.

```js
var app = function () {
    var self = this;

    var allBoxes = $('.box');
    var shadow = $('#shadow');
    var busy = false;

    self.init = function () {
        self.events();
    };

    self.getBoxLeftPosition = function(id)
    {
        var left = 100;

        if (id == 'box2')
        {
            left = 300;
        } else if (id == 'box3')
        {
            left = 500;
        } else if (id == 'box4')
        {
            left = 700;
        }

        return left;
    };

    self.events = function () {

        allBoxes.on('mouseover', function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            var currentBox = $(this);

            if (currentBox.hasClass('inactive') && !busy)
            {
                //busy = true;
                currentBox.removeClass('inactive').addClass('active').animate({
                    left: '-=30',
                    width: 260
                }, 400, function () {
                    //busy = false;
                });

                shadow.fadeIn(400);
            }
        });

        allBoxes.on('mouseout', function(event) {
            var currentBox = $(event.target);
            var leftValue = self.getBoxLeftPosition(currentBox.attr('id'));

            if (currentBox.length > 0)
            {
                currentBox.stop();
                currentBox.animate({
                    left: leftValue,
                    width: 200
                }, 300, 'swing', function () {
                    currentBox.removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
                }, 300);

                shadow.fadeOut(300);
            }
        });

    };

    return self;
};

var main = new app();
main.init();
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 420px;
}

.box div {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#box1 {
  left: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

#box2 {
  left: 300px;
  background: skyblue;
}

#box3 {
  left: 500px;
  background: orange;
}

#box4 {
  left: 700px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

#shadow {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  
  /*background: url('https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/Vz0GTzpQVaxmlIvvGgg64CSxcYBbHzu7gMQERduJ4qjU5HAg8KfisFFQvIqvKL5Vn7LIy6HZ=w1920-h916');*/
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);  /* transparent black */
  
  z-index: 10;
}

.inactive {
  z-index: 5;
}

.active {
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="box1" class="box inactive">
    <div id="copy1">Copy 1</div>
</div>

<div id="box2" class="box inactive">
    <div id="copy2">Copy 2</div>
</div>

<div id="box3" class="box inactive">
    <div id="copy3">Copy 3</div>
</div>

<div id="box4" class="box inactive">
    <div id="copy4">Copy 4</div>
</div>

<div id="shadow"></div>
```

Comment: this is buggy! try hovering on item1 and immediately hover to other items and do it many times.

Comment: Yep, it's still buggy.

Comment: It's still buggy : (

Comment: perhaps it was because of the gray part which doesn't cover 100% outside the scroll area. For now, just now, I set the #shadow width and height to a fixed size 1000x600px. See if the animation behavior works first. Later we can find out how to set the #shadow size correctly.